# Mainframes in every day life

Tags: mainframe

What are some examples of people using mainframes in every day life? Also, is it apparent really to the end-user that such a thing is running on a mainframe? I know ATM machines often use mainframes. Supposedly Farmland does too.

Answer (score 2):

Just so you know where im coming from, Im a 26 yr/old working on mainframes as we speak.

I think you would be surprised. Almost all banks use them for their core infrastructure. So although that means that the website where you do your transactions on doesnt run on a mainframe, your account details are on a mainframe. And all interbank transfers of money are done mainframe-to-mainframe.

Most large department stores, all transactions will be done on a mainframe. Have a look at their tellers. These are probably backed by a mainframe.

Airlines, Insurance agencies. telecom companies, Center-link (Government benefit agency) in Australia, has mainframes at their core. if you own a dishwasher, the manufacturing of that will have a mainframe, and possibly your car also. If you think of any company that would have benefitted heavily by computerised resources especially in the big end of town 30-40 years ago, you can bet their core infrastructure is mainframes.

Answer (score 1):

I have a vax in my garage that I use in every day life.  I've installed a dorm-sized fridge on the left, and use the remainder of the cabinet to store tools.